# DirectoryServices.AccountManagement UserPrincipal allows to login with the old password after the password is reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, form-authentication

I have implemented the form based authentication functionality in sharepoin 2010. For forget password functionality i am reseting the random password. But after calling the setpassword method it is still allowing user to login  with thier old password as well as new password. It should only allow user to login with new password. Below is my code.

```
           PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
           UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);

            AdUser adUser = new AdUser();

            if (user != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(randomPassword))
            {
                user.SetPassword(randomPassword);                  

            }
```

Below is the way i am authenticating the user.

bool status = SPClaimsUtility.AuthenticateFormsUser(Context.Request.UrlReferrer, txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());

Any help will be appreciated.